# Dragtable Javascript library isn't working for every page. Only in Index.html where library is imported?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use dragtable Javascript library for my Project.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/dragtable.js'></script>
```

```
<div class="div_wrapper" >

    <table id="table1" class="unassignedMerchants draggable" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in tenUnassignedMerchants">
                <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In index.html page it's working correctly but when I'm trying to use it in another .html page which is part of the project it's not working. 
What is the way to make this library visible for other pages?

Answer (score 0):

It`s depending of how add this library and how it connect with yours component.

For example how components know that it`s gradable. It could add directive as class or as attribute to yours elements...

Comment: Other pages are connected to index.html using ng-view directive

Comment: Yep, but how component know that it's gradable, as I saw from you code, you add **draggable** class. What about component? How you connect with this library?

Comment: I thought <script type="text/javascript" src='js/dragtable.js'></script> would be enogh. Is there anything I must add.